# Agile-uploader redirect to a 404 on form submission

Tags: php, jquery, flash, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm using on an old project [agile-uploader](http://old.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html), now that I've changed the server, it's giving an `404 error` when submitting the `form` to given `form_action`(page), although this webpage doest exist.

**Ps:** I'm using `php 5.4` now, but it was working on `php 5.2`.

Here is the code to import `agile-uploader` plugin:

```
$('#file-upload').agileUploader({  
    submitRedirect: 'upload/finish',  
    formId: 'form',  
    flashSrc: '/js/agile-uploader/agile-uploader.swf',  
    flashVars: {  
        form_action: 'upload/index',   
        max_width: '100',  
        max_height: '100',  
        file_limit: 20  
    }  
});
```

Comment: you need to provide some detail about your implementation. this is to vague as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with apache httpd module `fcgi`. And it was resolved by increasing max request length `FcgidMaxRequestLen`.